# Erro no bundle install no travis

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, travis-ci

Ao executar o trigger a build no travis, o travis aponta o seguinte erro. Ruby version 2.3.3 e rails version 5.1.7. Segue o travis.yml
[image: Error]
[image: Travis.yml]

Answer (score 0):

Aqui está um travis.yml meu que está funcionando normalmente:

```
language: ruby
cache: bundler
rvm:
- 2.4.5
before_install:
- gem update --system
- gem install bundler
env:
  global:
  - RACK_ENV=test
  - RAILS_ENV=test
  - trecho omidído
script:
- bundle install --jobs=3 --retry=3
- RAILS_ENV=test bundle exec rake db:schema:load --trace
- bundle exec rake db:test:prepare
- bundle exec rspec
```

Tente rodar o **gem update --system** antes de instalar o bundler. Verifique também se é necessário especificar a versão do bundler. Outra coisa: coloque o cache: bundler na configuração ;)